# Pip does not delete source after successful build

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am installing Ansible from github using Ansible's pip module (pip 7.1.2 on Debian):

```
- pip:
    name: "git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git#egg=ansible"
    state: latest
  become: yes
```

Then on the subsequent runs I get the message:

> fatal: [ansibletarget]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/pip install -U -e git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git#egg=ansible", "failed": true, "msg": "stdout: Obtaining ansible from git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git#egg=ansible\n  Updating ./src/ansible clone\n  Complete output from command git reset --hard -q origin/master:\n  \n  ----------------------------------------\n\n:stderr:   Could not find a tag or branch 'origin/master', assuming commit.\nfatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.\nUse '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:\n'git  [...] -- [...]'\nCommand \"git reset --hard -q origin/master\" failed with error code 128 in /tmp/src/ansible\n"}

In `/tmp/src` I have an `ansible` subdirectory along with `pip-delete-this-directory.txt` file. Pip does not delete it though.

The same behaviour (downloaded, not deleted, error on subsequent calls) occurs with:

```
pip install -U -e git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git#egg=ansible
```

Basically I want my playbook to be idempotent. I can delete the destination folder prior to installation and that solves the problem, however what is missing so that `pip` does not delete the contents as its content suggests:

```
This file is placed here by pip to indicate the source was put
here by pip.

Once this package is successfully installed this source code will be
deleted (unless you remove this file).
```

Comment: I changed name="git+https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git@devel#egg=ansible" state=latest and it worked for subsequent runs.

Comment: It saved source due to error, so you will be able to check it by yourself and see where is the problem. Also anything under /tmp will be deleted automatically, it is just a temporary folder.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you managed to solve it? I noticed clever_bassi's answer but i'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be hard to achieve idempotent behaviour with this setup. You can work around it by writing code that checks out the repository and if the repository is already checked out just do a git pull origin master and some pip work. The question is do you really want that?

There is a release repository specifically for getting a packaged up version of Ansible that is much more suitable for this scenario than trying to pip install it.

Debian specific installation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-debian